# iOS Plugin for Unity with Navigation to Add New Contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, plugins

I am making an iOS Plugin for an AR Unity App. When the user presses on a button, "Add Contact", they should be navigated to the Native iPhone add contact screen with the contact details already filled in. The user can then confirm adding the new contact and navigate back to the Unity App.

I have made the functionality work using the directlyAddContact method (see below). In this method the new contact is correctly added, but it happens behind the scenes with no notification to the user rather than navigating to the native add contact screen.

I am fairly certain the issue with my code are these lines:

```
CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForUnknownContact:contact];
controller.contactStore = store;
controller.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
```

I am guessing that ViewController and delegate are not working because Unity is controlling the View. I tried to research some forums and tutorials on overriding the UnityViewController with a native ViewController through a plugin, but I wasn't able to translate any of them to my specific issue.

Any additional help or insight would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code for my Unity Plugin, "MyPlugin.mm".

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>
#import <ContactsUI/ContactsUI.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyPlugin: UIViewController<CNContactViewControllerDelegate>
{
    NSDate * creationDate;
}
@end

@implementation MyPlugin

static MyPlugin *_sharedInstance;

+(MyPlugin*) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"Creating MyPlugin shared instance");
        _sharedInstance = [[MyPlugin alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

-(void)directlyAddContact:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName email:(NSString *)email phone:(NSString *)phone {

    // Create New Contact
    CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];

    // Add Name to Contact
    contact.givenName = firstName;
    contact.familyName = lastName;

    // Add Phone Number to Contact
    CNLabeledValue *workPhone = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:phone]];
    contact.phoneNumbers = @[workPhone];

    // Add Email to Contact

    // Save the newly created contact
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    CNSaveRequest *saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
    [saveRequest addContact:contact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];
    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Added %@ %@ at %@", contact.givenName, contact.familyName, contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue);
    [store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&error];
}

-(void)addContact:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName email:(NSString *)email phone:(NSString *)phone {

    // Create Store
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    // Create New Contact
    CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];

    // Add Name to Contact
    contact.givenName = firstName;
    contact.familyName = lastName;

    // Add Phone Number to Contact
    CNLabeledValue *workPhone = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:phone]];
    contact.phoneNumbers = @[workPhone];

    // Add Email to Contact

    // Create Controller and Delegate
    CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForUnknownContact:contact];
    controller.contactStore = store;
    controller.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
}


-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}


@end

extern "C"
{
    void IOSaddContact(const char* firstName, const char* lastName, const char* email, const char* phone)
    {
        NSString *firstNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:firstName];
        NSString *lastNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:lastName];
        NSString *phoneString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:phone];
        NSString *emailString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:email];

        return [[MyPlugin sharedInstance] addContact:firstNameString lastName:lastNameString email:emailString phone:phoneString];
    }

    void IOSdirectlyAddContact(const char* firstName, const char* lastName, const char* email, const char* phone)
    {
        NSString *firstNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:firstName];
        NSString *lastNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:lastName];
        NSString *phoneString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:phone];
        NSString *emailString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:email];

        return [[MyPlugin sharedInstance] directlyAddContact:firstNameString lastName:lastNameString email:emailString phone:phoneString];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the delegate method in your code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more? Is this the delegate method: [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true]; If not, I might not have a delegate method which might be part of my problem.

Comment: Is your CNContactViewController present on the screen?

Comment: I don't think it is. I start off the plugin by extending UIViewController<CNContactViewControllerDelegate>, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient. What do I need to do to ensure the CNContactViewController is present on the screen?

Comment: Have you tried using official Unity sample code?

Comment: I have tried Unity sample code, but have not been able to find any sample code to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I have found sample code to return a timestamp or to show a native alert, but not to navigate to a native screen such as adding contacts.

Comment: I believe problem is in this part of code:  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];`

Comment: Thank you 0xBFE1A8. Do you have any suggestions on what to replace that problematic code with?

Comment: try this: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController: controller animated:true completion: NULL];`

Comment: That is definitely getting me closer. Before nothing was happening, now it's giving me the error "[General] Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or file a Radar." And then it seem to be trying to change the view, because it then continues to log "[CNUI ERROR] Contact view delayed appearance timed out."

Comment: does your app crash?

Comment: Somewhat. After call is made, the AR Camera continues to work, but it does not register any new user input.

Comment: Ahh I understand your problem, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts?language=objc) documentation, Privacy title.